# Find duplicates in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, vue.js

The following code I have on the controller is below.

```php
public function add(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'userSelected' => 'required',
        'projectSelected' => 'required',
    ]);

    $researcherToProject = new ProjectResearchers();
    $researcherToProject->user_id = $request->userSelected;
    $researcherToProject->project_id = $request->projectSelected;
    $researcherToProject->created_at = Carbon::now();
    $researcherToProject->updated_at = Carbon::now();
    $researcherToProject->save();

    return new ProjectsResearchersResource($researcherToProject);
}
```

Should I make another validation or create a function?

Ex: I create a user id "5" with project id "13" and user id "2" with project id "17". If I try creating again a user id "5" with project id "13" it allows me, so I get two times the same data in the database. How do I avoid duplicate entries?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `updateOrCreate` method, the first array is the unique values that you are looking for, if not found it will create the entry, if it finds them it will just update the fields in the second array so do this instead:

```
public function add(Request $request){

    $request->validate([
        'userSelected' => 'required', 
        'projectSelected' => 'required',     
    ]);

    $researcherToProject = ProjectResearchers::updateOrCreate(
        ['user_id' => $request->userSelected, 'project_id' => $request->projectSelected],
        ['created_at' => Carbon::now(), 'updated_at' => Carbon::now()] 
    );

    return new ProjectsResearchersResource($researcherToProject);
}
```

or if you don't want to update at all, you can just check if it exists before storing:

```
public function add(Request $request){

    $request->validate([
        'userSelected' => 'required', 
        'projectSelected' => 'required',     
    ]);

       $researcherToProject = new ProjectResearchers(); 

    if( ! ProjectResearchers::where('user_id', $request->userSelected)->where('project_id', $request->projectSelected)->exists()) {
       $researcherToProject = new ProjectResearchers(); 
       $researcherToProject->user_id = $request->userSelected;
       $researcherToProject->project_id = $request->projectSelected;
       $researcherToProject->created_at = Carbon::now();
       $researcherToProject->updated_at = Carbon::now();

       $researcherToProject->save();
    } else {
        $researcherToProject = ProjectResearchers::where('user_id', $request->userSelected)->where('project_id', $request->projectSelected)->first(); 
    }

    return new ProjectsResearchersResource($researcherToProject);
}
```

Comment: please accept the answer if you found it helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Additionaly to @nakov answer:

`firstOrCreate()` can combine 2 ways and looks cleaner:

```
public function add(Request $request){
    $request->validate([
        'userSelected' => 'required', 
        'projectSelected' => 'required',     
    ]);

    $researcherToProject = ProjectResearchers::firstOrCreate([
        'user_id' => $request->userSelected,
        'project_id' => $request->projectSelected
    ]); 

    $researcherToProject->created_at = Carbon::now();
    $researcherToProject->updated_at = Carbon::now();
    $researcherToProject->save();

    return new ProjectsResearchersResource($researcherToProject);
}
```

Or if you don't want to update:

```
public function add(Request $request){
    $request->validate([
        'userSelected' => 'required', 
        'projectSelected' => 'required',     
    ]);

    $researcherToProject = ProjectResearchers::firstOrCreate([
        'user_id' => $request->userSelected,
        'project_id' => $request->projectSelected
    ]);

    if(!$researcherToProject->id){
        $researcherToProject->created_at = Carbon::now();
        $researcherToProject->updated_at = Carbon::now();
        $researcherToProject->save();
    }

    return new ProjectsResearchersResource($researcherToProject);
}
```